# Non Muslim family

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, family

Assalam ´aleykoum,
It may sound stupid, but if I talk with my non-Muslim family,that don’t know I’m Muslim,about Muslims and Islam, and I talk about Muslims as « they » like this time I said « if they don’t say the name of Allah right it’s not good », is it like bad, like if I separate myself from other Muslim